# Android requestLocationUpdates minimumtime + minimumdistance don't really work

Tags: android, locationlistener

```
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
```

I understand that this line of code is supposed to update the device location as frequently as possible right? Specifically, every 0miliseconds and 0metres (minimum).

Okay, the word '**minimum**' is key here but still, why sometimes the location is not updated for maybe as long as 30+ seconds? I have timed the actual time between one update and the next, while on WiFi, and it took 38 seconds even though I had 0 and 0 in the code. I even tried it with 1000ms (1second) but still doesn't update as frequent.

How do I make this update more frequently? Why does it respond this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't (make it update more frequently).

The documentation indicates that you will get "updates as frequently as possible" if you specify min_distance and min_time as zero. So what you are seeing is "as frequently as possible". Usually you won't get an update unless something has changed, so if you aren't moving you won't necessarily get an update. Also, since you are using Network location and not GPS, the accuracy of locations isn't that good so you shouldn't expect updates that frequently.

Also, each hardware vendor implements the location providers differently. So the frequency of updates is determined by the hardware vendor's implementation.

Comment: What you just said just confirms what I was afraid was true :) Concerning the GPS, would it be okay to send 2 requestLocationUpdates to the same listener? One using the GPS_PROVIDER and other using NETWORK_PROVIDER. Like this


    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

Comment: yes, you can request multiple different types of location updates. However, be aware that requesting GPS updates "as frequently as possible" will drain the battery "as fast as possible", so you shouldn't do it for very long or unless you know that the device is plugged in to a power source.

Comment: Not only drain on battery, but also heat up the phone :).